# Unable to consume a webapi from link in an email

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm testing a webapi that sends email with a link for user verification, I receive the email, but when I click the link, it does not verify the user via the email link, instead I get the below error

> No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:4000/account/verify-email?token={token}

see below code in controller for the verification

```
[HttpPost("verify-email")]
        public IActionResult VerifyEmail(VerifyEmailRequest model)
        {
            _accountService.VerifyEmail(model.Token);
            return Ok(new { message = "Verification successful, you can now login" });
        }
```

see code in services class

```
public void VerifyEmail(string token)
{
    var account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.VerificationToken == token);

    if (account == null) throw new AppException("Verification failed");

    account.Verified = DateTime.UtcNow;
    account.VerificationToken = null;

    _context.Accounts.Update(account);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that clicking on a Link performs a GET request instead a POST request. So you may change `[HttpPost("verify-email")]` to `[HttpGet("verify-email")]`

Comment: When you get a 404 error trying to access your site, you should immediately begin checking things like routes and HTTP verbs to make sure that the URL you're requesting lines up with the endpoints that you're exposing. Either the URL is wrong, the route/verb is wrong, or some combination of all of those.

Comment: `http://localhost:4000/account/verify-email?token={token}` I just want to confirm: do you know that localhost will only work on the computer that is running the web server? also clearly `{token}` is not a valid value - is that what is in your link?

Comment: {token} is not what's in the link an actual token is generated

Answer (score 0):

Code true working,
You need check http://localhost:4000/account/verify-email?token={token} url.

You send this url. Your project working in Localhost:4000?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have:

```
[Route("account")]
```

At the top

Comment: adding [Route("account")]  did not work as the controller already has routing enabled at the top

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).